# Parsing a SOAP response using XPath Java

Tags: java, xml, xpath

I am new to XPath. I have the following SOAP response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap:Body>
        <addParentResponse xmlns="urn:JadeWebServices/NetsuiteCustomer/">
            <addParentResult>Organisation xxxxx already exists - use UpdateParent method instead</addParentResult>
        </addParentResponse>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Can anyone kindly give me some code which will read the value of "addParentResult"?

Regards,
Anirban.

Comment: Did the below answer work for you?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following xpath should give the desired result :

`/soap:Envelope/soap:Body/parentns:addParentResponse/parentns:addParentResult/text()`

The reason I added `parentns` to xpath is that your xml has namespaces and your xpath processor should know about them. But the `addParentResponse` has no prefix and has default namespace. In this case add a prefix in xpath expression and before doing that tell xpath processor that for the `parentns` prefix there is a value which is `"urn:JadeWebServices/NetsuiteCustomer/"`. It is done via a [`NamespaceContext`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/namespace/NamespaceContext.html).

Also be sure to tell the `DocumentBuilderFactory` that it should be aware of namespaces by using `setNamespaceAware( true );`

Code in Java would be :

```
    try 
    {
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        dbf.setNamespaceAware(true);
        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();

        Document doc = db.parse( new File( "soapResponse.xml" ) );

        XPathFactory xPathFactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
        XPath xpath = xPathFactory.newXPath();
        javax.xml.namespace.NamespaceContext ns = new javax.xml.namespace.NamespaceContext()
        {

            @Override
            public String getNamespaceURI(String prefix) 
            {
                if ( "soap".equals( prefix ) )
                {
                    return "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/";
                }
                else if ( "xsi".equals( prefix ) )
                {
                    return "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance";
                }
                else if ( "xsd".equals( prefix ) )
                {
                    return "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema";
                }
                else if ( "xml".equals( prefix ) )
                {
                    return javax.xml.XMLConstants.XML_NS_URI;
                }
                else if ( "parentns".equals( prefix ) )
                {
                    return "urn:JadeWebServices/NetsuiteCustomer/";
                }

                return javax.xml.XMLConstants.NULL_NS_URI;
           }

           @Override
           public String getPrefix(String namespaceURI) 
           {
              return null;
           }

            @Override
            public Iterator<?> getPrefixes(String namespaceURI) 
            {
                return null;
            }

        };


         xpath.setNamespaceContext(ns);
         XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile( "/soap:Envelope/soap:Body/parentns:addParentResponse/parentns:addParentResult/text()" );


         Object exprEval = expr.evaluate( doc, XPathConstants.STRING );
         if ( exprEval != null )
         {
            System.out.println( "The text of addParentResult is : " + exprEval );
         }
    }
    catch ( Exception e )
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
 }
```

To test this code, put your xml in a file called `soapResponse.xml` at the same level as your java file.

Output from `System.out.println()` is :

`The text of addParentResult is : Organisation xxxxx already exists - use UpdateParent method instead`